# under determined system solution python

Tags: python, math, linear-algebra

**Goal:**
calculate a vector from under determined linear system (2x3) **Ax = b** 
 The third equation should be unity equation (x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1).
I have correct matrix coefficients, but can't get the correct result;
trying to solve **Ax = b** in this way:

Function returns null space of an operator. Then I'm setting matrix and trying to solve it.

```
from scipy.linalg import qr, null_space, svd
from scipy import transpose, compress

def null(A, eps=1e-17):
    u, s, vh = svd(A)
    padding = max(0,np.shape(A)[1]-np.shape(s)[0])
    null_mask = np.concatenate(((s <= eps), np.ones((padding,),dtype=bool)),axis=0)
    null_space = compress(null_mask, vh, axis=0)
    return transpose(null_space)
```

We have 3 vertices that set a triangle:

```
vh0 = [0., -1., 0.]
vh1 = [-0.03806, -0.98078501, -0.191341]
vh2 = [-0.074658, -0.98078501, -0.18024001]

# normal vector of vh0
normal_vec = [ 0., -0.23760592, 0.]

cap_vec10 = np.subtract(vh1, vh0)
cap_vec20 = np.subtract(vh2, vh0)

a1 = np.array(np.subtract(cap_vec20, cap_vec10))
a2 = np.array(np.dot(-1, capvec10))

# orientation bit of the normal vector
ob = np.sign(np.linalg.det([x_k, x_k1, normal_vec])) 

# normal vector of vertex vh1 that I want to get solving the system
normal_vec1 = [-0.04744975, -0.97674069, -0.209108]

Lm   = np.dot(np.subtract(vh2, vh1), normal_vec1) 
Lm_1 = np.dot(np.subtract(vh0, vh1), normal_vec1) 

# solving under determined system
A = np.array([a1, a2]) 
b = np.array([Lm, Lm_1])
x_lstsq = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0]
wanted_norm = np.sqrt(abs(1 - (np.linalg.norm(x_lstsq)*np.linalg.norm(x_lstsq))))

Z = null(A)*wanted_norm 
new_normal_vec = np.add(Z[:, 0], x_lstsq)

if np.sign(np.linalg.det([x_k, x_k1, Z[:, 0]])) != ob:
    new_normal_vec[list(np.abs(x_lstsq)).index(min(np.abs(x_lstsq)))] *= ob

print("should_be:   {}\ncounted_nv:  {}".format(np.round(normal_vec1, 3), np.round(new_normal_vec, 3)))
```

normal_vec1 is the vector that I need. And for both vectors Z*vector == 1.

Coefficients in the code: L_m = < vector, normal_vector >, <> - scalar multiplication

As I understood, two equations set a line, and normalization gives a unity sphere. So my solution is crossing points of line and the unity sphere. But, also can't understand how to get both solutions.

Comment: Please show a complete code snippet, including all import statements and data definitions. As it is now, I do not fully understand what you are doing and cannot test your code. Read and follow [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: You can't solve it with the usual techniques.  You need to use a singular value decomposition solver when you have more unknowns than equations.

Comment: That is what I'm trying to do

Comment: Is it necessary to solve the problem using np.linalg functions? If you just need to implement the solution somehow, one way to go about it is to find a general solution and paste it into some Python code. For a 2x3 system the general solution is not too messy. You could work it out by hand or use a software package. Let me know if you want to go down that road.

Comment: @robert-dodier , it is no necessary to use numpy, want  to try your solution. Probably it is about solving squared equation, rigth?

Comment: Alex, I on't completely understand the problem to be solved. You mentioned something about a triangle and then something else about a sphere. Can you state exactly what is the original problem that is to be solved? I think it might be important for myself and others in order to help you figure out a solution.

Comment: Probably, I didn't mention the normalizing equation and that's why my question was in-understandable. But all I waned was to get the second solution through the null space of matrix A. The presented code was shown after the first comment. Hope next time my question will be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the pseudoinverse np.linalg.pinv function: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.pinv.html

Comment: Thank you. But is nor it for the full systems? Because I have under determined and there are several solutions (I think at least two), and I want to get them all. So I will be able to chose appropriate using some constraints.

Comment: Well,if there are at least two, then there are infinite solutions. What you might want to do is get a matrix Z(kernel generator) such that all all elements in the kernel are of the form Z*p for some p. Then your solution set is { v+Z*p} where v is the solution the pseudoinverse gives.

Comment: See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.null_space.html, you can generate your kernel with that tool.

Comment: I already did it in this line: null(A) (also have tried scipy.linalg.null space, got the same result). This is kernel. But as I understood, two of three equations give a line, and normalization (that is unity sphere) gives to points. So, my problem is to find both of them.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understand what you are trying to do here. Your problem is  not with finding the solutions of your matrix then, but with finding specific points in the solution space?  by "normalization" you mean finding the points in the solution space that have norm 1? If so consider subtracting the vector in the kernel instead of adding it. You might also want to use this approach instead: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93sphere_intersection, you just solve a quadratic equation.

Answer (score 0):

**The goal was :** basically solve the linear under determined system 2x3 with a constraint that resulting vector should be normalized.

 What I did that give one of the solutions (because there are from 0 to 2 vectors in 3D space):

*1. Calculated least squared solution:*

```
x_lstsq = np.linalg.lstsq(A, b)[0]
```

*2. Calculated null space (kernel of the operator A)*

```
wanted_norm = np.sqrt(abs(1 - (np.linalg.norm(x_lstsq)*np.linalg.norm(x_lstsq))))
Z = null(A)*wanted_norm
```

*3. Calculated the resulting vector*

```
result = np.add(Z[:, 0], x_lstsq)
```

In this way I was getting one of two vectors that wasn't correct for my project, but was correct for this particular linear system. So my question was: how to get the second one doing the same steps (through the nullity space).

During the process of finding the solution I realized another one:
basically solve this linear system by hand, using the equation of normalization as the third equation. 
Geometrically both first two equations sets two planes. The crossing of these planes gives a line. Such equation: x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1 sets unity sphere. So, crossing of this line and this sphere gives us two points. Therefore, solving squared equation of one of the coordinates gives you form 0 to 2 roots (from 0 to 2 vectors).